# «Каждый поступает(,) как умеет, большего не дано». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Уважаемые эксперты, подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не стоит запятая перед «как» в этом предложении? (Увидел в книге Джека Лондона.)

> *Каждый поступает **как** умеет, большего не дано.*

Comment: Это как наречие, поэтому запятой нет, верно?

Comment: _Каждый поступает как умеет, большего не надо._ ТАК Вы написали в своем вопросе. Но у Д. Лондона предложение другое: _Каждый поступает как умеет, большего не **дано._** https://quote-citation.com/topic/martin-iden

Comment: Да, ошибся, когда печатал. Возможно, т9 выдал, а я не заметил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Каждый поступает **как умеет**, большего не дано.*

Ответ на этот вопрос можно **найти в словаре.**

ПОСТУПИТЬ, св. 1. **КАК** Совершить по отношению к кому-л. действие, оцениваемое каким-л. образом; действовать каким-л. образом в отношении кого-л. П. благородно, безрассудно. П. правильно, хорошо, плохо. П. по справедливости, по-человечески. **П. как велит совесть.**

В данном случае у глагола **сильное управление, обозначенное прямо в словарной статье**, а оборот ***как умеет*** занимает позицию наречия, отвечает на вопрос КАК, поэтому он не обособляется.

В сочетании **с другими глаголами** оборот может обособляться или не обособляться, что зависит от структуры, от расстановки ударений. Тогда и можно говорить о том, насколько **тесная там связь со сказуемым**, например:

Каждый выживает **как умеет**.  [Михаил Елизаров. Госпиталь (2009)]

―  Как никогда,  ― заулыбался капитан. ―  Тогда не мешайте мне работать, каждый кормится, **как умеет**.[Евгений Сухов.  (2007)]

― Ты не бойся, это она улыбается, ― шепнул Игорь. ― Старается, **как умеет.** [Александр Силаев. (2007)]

Answer (score 3):

Чувствуется тесная связь сказуемого с последующим "как умеет", поэтому запятая не ставится. Если убрать это "как...", то останется непонятная, как бы незавершённая, основа "Каждый поступает". 
И если правильнее сказать, то оборот с союзом "как" входит в состав сказуемого.

Answer (score 2):

Каждый поступает (как?) как умеет, большего не надо.

**Как умеет - обстоятельство образа действия**, без которого сказуемое непонятно. Обычно сочетание с **как** заменяют наречием-синонимом, но в данном случае это проблематично, если только сочетанием **по своим возможностям**. Но это явно не сравнительный оборот, и СПП получается некорректным, тогда бы было: Каждый поступает так, как умеет, большего не надо.

Comment: Это **сравнительный оборот**. Но он не обособляется, если тесно связан со сказуемым.

Comment: А что с чем здесь сравнивается?

Comment: На первом месте здесь значение обстоятельства образа действия, здесь только вид сравнения, об этом я и говорю

Comment: В соответствующем пункте Розенталя оборот назван сравнительным. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147

Comment: У Розенталя: . При анализе подобных примеров мы исходим из авторской пунктуации и пытаемся ее объяснить... Так, сопоставляя приведенные выше предложения из стихотворений М. Ю. Лермонтова с его же фразой Она ускользнёт, как змея, порхнёт и умчится, как птичка, мы можем допустить, что в последнем случае автору важно было создать художественные образы путем, так сказать, чистого сравнения (подобно змее, подобно птичке, хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой, но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147   4

Comment: Так что он тоже разделяет чистое сравнение и оттенок обстоятельства образа действия.

Comment: Так это совсем другое правило. А здесь следующее: если сравнительный оборот входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота).

Comment: Сказуемое здесь поступает. Тесно связан - да.